# Routes not working when directly typed on address bar with angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm working on angular-meteor. I defined routes like this:

```
    angular.module('myapp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $stateProvider
        .state('homepage', {

           url: '/homepage',
           template: '<mycomponent></mycomponent>'
        })

        .state('anotherpage', {

          url: '/other-route',
          template: '<othercomponent></othercomponent>'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/homepage');
    });
```

Everything works just fine until I directly type the url to /other-route direcrly in the address bar. Browser just goes back to /homepage. Hints? Thanks.

Comment: `<other-component>` and `<othercomponent` are two different tags, the latter being illegal. Moreover have you tried removing *hyphens* in your routes altogether?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I just re-edited and tried to remove hyphens from the routes but nothing changes.

Comment: Turn off `html5Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using ASP.Net then you need to configure the global.asax file with

```js
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/Index.html";

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;


  string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
  if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)))
    Context.RewritePath(ROOT_DOCUMENT);
}
```

Also the index.html needs the base tag

```js
<base href="/">
```

and add this to the end of the app.config section

```js
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: ASP.net? I'm using Meteor.js with angular.

Comment: Try remove the hmtl5 mode and try the directy URL with the # then you will know if its HTML5 mode related or not. Might narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried but nothing changes even with HTML5 mode off. I can only navigate through routes starting from the homepage.

Comment: What I explained above did it for me, it work the same as you said but if I hit F5 or type it in it did not work. I had to sort it at the root and that fixed my problem since your not using .net I can't advise but you code above is sound because I use web api so look else where I did put my $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); at the end but not sure if that matters